# Superimposed Pins on Bing Maps - How to display metadata of both or move pins apart at a certain zoom

Tags: maps, bing-maps, bing, pushpin

I am generating an HTML/Javascript file from an Access365 database which plots pins on a Bing Map.  Each of the pins has associated metadata about the location it is pinning which is viewed by clicking the pin.  However, there can be pins which are at exactly the same location (lat and long) and only the metadata for the top pin is available.

How do I either show the combined metadata or have the pins move apart a bit say when the the user mouses over them?  Does anyone know how to do that?  I've gone round in circles looking at the MS documentation and can't find anything to help.

P.S. There is also a clusterLayer.  If that needs removing to solve the problem that's Ok but it would be better if it could stay.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    
        <!-- Reference to the Bing Maps SDK -->
        <script type='text/javascript'
                src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=[zzz]' 
                async defer></script>
        
        <script type='text/javascript'>
    
        function GetMap()
        {
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(53.50632, -7.2714), zoom:8});
    
            var ourBlue = 'rgb(108, 162, 212)';
            
             //Create an infobox at the center of the map but don't show it.
            infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), {
                visible: false
            });
    
            //Assign the infobox to a map instance.
            infobox.setMap(map);
    
            var theLocations = [3];
            var thePins = [3];
            theLocations[0] = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(53.41, -7.1);
            theLocations[1] = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(53.42, -7.1);
            theLocations[2] = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(53.43, -7.1);
            for (var i = 0; i < theLocations.length; i++){
                var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(theLocations[i]);
    
                pin.metadata = {
                title: 'Pin ' + i, description: 'Description for pin' + i
                };
        
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', pushpinClicked);
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mouseover', splitOverlap);   
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mouseout', function (e) {
                e.target.setOptions({ color:'purple' });
            });
            
                thePins[i] = pin; //add pin to array of pins            
                
            }
            
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule("Microsoft.Maps.Clustering", function(){
                clusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(thePins);
            map.layers.insert(clusterLayer);
            });
        
    
        }
        
        
        function splitOverlap(e) {
        var ourBlue = 'rgb(108, 162, 212)';
                e.target.setOptions({color:ourBlue});
                
            }           
    
        }
        
        function pushpinClicked(e) {
            //Make sure the infobox has metadata to display.
            if (e.target.metadata) {
                //Set the infobox options with the metadata of the pushpin.
                infobox.setOptions({
                    location: e.target.getLocation(),
                    title: e.target.metadata.title,
                    description: e.target.metadata.description,
                    visible: true
                });
            }
        }
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=Arvr3LDJsmNB-2OGHl_egpbP9RbwsYKGKrktnPBC06G38T9q3CzsfmwK6GNoW7R_' async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have clusters and you want to see individual metadate for items within the cluster there are two common approaches:

1. Have a popup that shows the first location metadata and buttons to step/page/tab through each item in the cluster.
2. Use the spider cluster visualization: https://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Clustering_SpiderClusters

Comment: Hi @rbrundritt.  Thanks for your reply and the link.  I had to get the job finished before I saw this unfortunately so I added a nudge to subsequent pins at the same longitude and latitude, just moving them down the street a few yards.  If the client asks me to revisit this, though, I will definitely follow your Spider Cluster idea, it looks like it would have been ideal!  Thanks!